# Val Loss is nan while Val Accuracy flucturates

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, batch-processing

I am trying to build a deep learning model, but the validation loss is staying at nan while the validation accuracy is increasing. I am using binary crossentropy as my loss function and I think it's because the function is taking log(0). Any idea on how to fix?

```
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import UnitNorm

#define two input layers
img_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (256,256,3), name = "image")
csv_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (4,), name = "csv")
# define layers for image data


tf.random.set_seed(123)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(img_input)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(16, (7,7), 1, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer= 'he_normal', kernel_constraint=UnitNorm(), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.00001), name = 'conv1_img')(x1)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(name="mxp1_img")(x1)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=1e-100, name = 'Dropout')(x1)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="flatten_img")(x1)

# define layers for csv data
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="flatten_csv")(csv_input)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name="dense1_csv")(x2)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name="dense2_csv")(x2)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name="dense3_csv")(x2)

# merge layers
x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x1,x2], name="concat_csv_img")
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', name="dense1_csv_img", kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-100))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=1e-100)(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', name="classify")(x) #CHANGE THIS TO 2 IF IT DOESN'T WORK

#make model with 2 inputs and 1 output
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[img_input, csv_input], outputs=output) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Above is creating the model

[Here is the epoch history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGep2.png)